# Django translation : assess if a string is a translation in any available language

Tags: django, internationalization

I can't find a way to identify if a given string (say "xxxxxxxxxx") is a translation of a defined string (say "hello world"), in any available language (the languages my application is translated into). I'm inputted a string, and would like to identify if it's a translation of "hello world" in any of my available languages (PO files then). Any idea ?

EDIT for context : The application previously exported a database in a fixed XLS format, for future imports. During the import, a formatting check is done and an error message is thrown if format is wrong. That formatting check begins with reading the tabs name. If it's good --> then the XLS is read, if not the error is thrown. During that first check, I want to discriminate between (i) a real error in formatting and (ii) the user importing an XLS previously exported in a different language (but I don't know which one). So I have the tab name and just want to check if that tab name is just a translation of the default tab name : that would allow me to throw a different error message advising to change to the correct language for importing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think what you are trying to do is achievable using django. (Why do you want to do this BTW?)

There is a  library out there named polib. It handles `.po` and `.mo` files very nicely. You can read its documentation [here](https://polib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html).

You can create a pofile object with it using

```
import polib

po = polib.pofile('<FILE_PATH>')
```

And then iterate over it like this

```
for entry in po:
    msgid, msgstr = po.msgid, po.msgstr
    # you can do your comparison here
```

Comment: Thanks Nafees. I edited for context. Also, thanks for pointing to that library. I would have prefered a straightforward method, but I'll try that one. Thanks again